# inotifywait not working when folder is deleted and re-created

Tags: linux, mount, directory, monitoring, inotify

I am trying to use inotifywait to monitor a folder:

```
inotifywait -m -r /home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder
```

The command works and if I create files in that folder, all seems to work correctly.

While the folder is being monitored, if I delete it, I get the following output:

```
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ MOVE_SELF 
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ OPEN,ISDIR 
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR 
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ MOVE_SELF 
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ ATTRIB,ISDIR 
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ OPEN,ISDIR 
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ DELETE Untitled Document
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ DELETE Untitled Document 2
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR 
/home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder/ DELETE_SELF
```

If I then re-create that folder again, while the monitoring is still taking place, inotifywait doesn't seem to continue monitoring it, unless I run `inotifywait -m -r /home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder` again.

How do I get around this issue?  I basically want to monitor a USB stick which will be plugged in and removed many times during a day.  When it's unplugged and plugged back in, I think inotifywait will stop monitoring it, the same way the folder above was deleted and re-created where inotifywait wasn't able to continue monitoring it, unless I run the above command again, i.e. `inotifywait -m -r /home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder`

Should I be using something more appropriate for such tasks and not use inotifywait?  cron is not suitable for my needs, as I am not after time based actions, I am after event based actions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, if you delete a folder that `inotifywait` is watching, then, yes, it will stop watching it. The obvious way around that is simply to monitor the directory one level up (you could even create a directory to monitor especially and put your `work_folder` in there.

However this won't work if you have a folder underneath which is unmounted/remounted rather than deleted/re-created, the two are very different processes. I have no idea if using something other than `inotifywait` is the best thing here since I have no idea what you are trying to to achieve by monitoring the directory. However perhaps the best thing to do is to set up a `udev` rule to call as script which mounts the USB stick and starts the `inotifywait` process when it is plugged in and another to stop it again when it is unplugged.

You would put the `udev` rules in a .rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d` directory. The rules would look something like:

```
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="dev_id_serial", ACTION=="add", \
  RUN+="/path/to/script add '%E{DEVNAME}'"
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="dev_id_serial", ACTION=="remove", \
  RUN+="/path/to/script remove '%E{DEVNAME}'"
```

Where `ID_SERIAL` for the device can be determined by:

```
udevadm info --name=/path/to/device --query=property
```

with the script something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

pid_file=/var/run/script_name.pid
out_file=/var/log/script_name.log

# try to kill previous process even with add in case something
# went wrong with last remove
if [ "$1" = add ] || [ "$1" = remove ]; then
  pid=$(cat "$pid_file")
  [ "$(ps -p "$pid" -o comm=)" = inotifywait ] && kill "$pid"
fi

if [ "$1" = add ]; then
  /bin/mount "$2" /home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder
  /usr/bin/inotifywait -m -r /home/oshiro/Desktop/work_folder \
    </dev/null >"$out_file" 2>&1 &
  echo $! >"$pid_file"
fi
```

Also, make sure that the mounting via the `udev` rule does not conflict with and other process which may try to automatically mount the disk when it is plugged in.